# Как поставить ограничение кликов по кнопке в реальном времени?

Tags: jquery, javascript, php

Всем привет!
Задался недавно вопросом: Как можно реализовать ограничение кликов по кнопке в реальном времени? 
Допустим, стоит ограничение в 10 кликов на кнопки. Кликнул первый Вася по кнопке у Пети появилось "Осталось 9 кликов". После 10-ого нажатия кнопка деактивируется. 
Я предполагаю, что без БД не обойтись.

Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 3):

Записываем кол-во кликов в бд. На сайте например каждые 10 сек кидаем AJAX запрос, который возвращает кол-во оставшихся кликов, проверяем, если кол-во оставшихся кликов = 0, то дисайблим кнопку.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за мгновенный ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Всё, что касается «в реальном времени» делается по технологии [Comet](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet) — когда браузер держит открытое соединение с сервером, и тот может передать ему инфу в любой момент, не дожидаясь нового запроса от браузера.

По клику на кнопку у Васи, на сервер отправляется событие, которое тут же распостраняется другим Петям в этой же "комнате", что мгновенно декрементирует счетчики кнопки у них.

Где хранить текущее значение счётчика — хоть в БД, хоть прямо в памяти, это уже детали.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за мгновенный ответ!
"Хранить текущее значение счётчика в памяти" - это интересно!
А можно ли увидеть небольшой примерчик? Либо посоветуйте, пожалуйста, хорошую литературу по "реальному времени". Чувствую непоследний раз прийдётся обращаться к технологии Comet. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли стоит такие данные держать в БД вроде MySQL, для этого скорее подойдут более быстрые Redis или даже MemCached (хоть он немного не для того, но на хостингах он чаще встречается).

Comment: Спасибо Вам за мгновенный ответ!